\ContinuedFloat with threeparttable not working
\ContinuedFloat doesn't work for threeparttable environments. Only the last two have the same number which restarts after the first table. Here is an MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{\\ Table Caption}
\label{tab:test}
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YYYYY} 
\midrule \midrule
& & & & \\
(1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\
& & & & \\    
\midrule \midrule
\multicolumn{5}{r}{continued on next page}
\end{tabularx}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{\\ Table Caption (Continued)}
\ContinuedFloat
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YYYYY} 
\midrule \midrule
& & & & \\
(1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\
& & & & \\    
\midrule \midrule
\multicolumn{5}{r}{continued on next page}
\end{tabularx}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{\\Table caption (Continued)}
\ContinuedFloat
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YYYYY} 
\midrule \midrule
& & & & \\
(1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\
& & & & \\
\midrule \midrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}
\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont
\item
\textit{Notes:}
This table shows ...
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}


This doesn't have anything to do with threeparttable, really.

never start a caption with \\  (unrelated to your question)

You need to issue \ContinuedFloat before the \caption since the float counter is incremented when calling \caption.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Table caption}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ *{5}{Y} }
      \toprule
      (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\
      \bottomrule
      \multicolumn{5}{r}{\small continued on next page}
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \centering
  \caption[]{Table caption (continued)}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ *{5}{Y} }
      \toprule
      (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\
      \bottomrule
      \multicolumn{5}{r}{\small continued on next page}
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \centering
  \caption[]{Table caption (continued)}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ *{5}{Y} }
      \toprule
      (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\
      \bottomrule
      \multicolumn{5}{r}{\small continued on next page}
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item
      \textit{Notes:} This table shows\ldots
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}

Also consider including the caption package to avoid multiple entries in your LoT (this is mentioned/suggested in the subfig documentation).

I don't think you need \multicolumn{5}{r}{\small continued on next page} in the third table. Also, the 3 \centering instructions do nothing useful since the target width of the tabularx environments is set to \textwidth in all cases.

Using threeparttable environments serves no discernible purpose in the first and second table environments of the sample code. The use of threeparttable in the third table environment is highly dubious, since (a) no \tnote directives are used anywhere, (b) there's no need to constrain the width of the tablenotes environment to that of the tabularx environment (since the latter's width is set to \textwidth), and (c) the tablenotes environment contains no truly meaningful \item directives. Point (c) is more or less a consequence of point (a), I suppose.
In short, I wouldn't bother with the threeparttable machinery for the tables at hand. Just place \ContinuedFloat instructions before, rather than after, the \caption directives in tables 2 and 3.
A separate issue: I'm assuming that \caption{\\ Table Caption (Continued)} is supposed to force a line break between "Table n" and the caption text. If this assumption is correct, this objective could be achieved far more robustly by loading the caption package with the options labelsep=newline and, if desired, singlelinecheck=false.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs,tabularx}
\captionsetup{labelsep=newline,
              singlelinecheck=false,
              skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{Table Caption}
\label{tab:test}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} YYYYY @{}} 
\toprule
(1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\   
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{\footnotesize continued on next page}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\ContinuedFloat
\caption{Table Caption (continued)}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} YYYYY @{}} 
\toprule
(1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\    
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{\footnotesize continued on next page}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\ContinuedFloat
\caption{Table caption (continued)}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} YYYYY @{}} 
\toprule
(1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\medskip  % no need for 'tablenotes'
\footnotesize
\textit{Notes:} This table shows \dots
\end{table}

\end{document}

